# SharePoint Flow to generate automatic filename

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to generate automatic filename to documents being made or being uploaded in SharePoint Document library. 
How can this be done with Flow?

I have created a calculated column in my list that creates the name i want the file to be renamed to, but i have no idea how i can use Flow to 
update the name using the calculated column.

Anyone that can help?

Comment: are you trying to create item OR trying to create a new file to library?

Comment: generate new filename to documents created or added to document library.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, you have created a calculated column in your list that creates the name you want the file to be renamed to.

I suggest you creating SharePoint designer workflow like the following:

[image]

[image]